# Find ratio formed by intersection of segments in a triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Question: Points $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{29}$ are drawn, in that order, on side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ so that
$$AP_1=P_1 P_2=P_2 P_3=\cdots=P_{29} B$$
Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $Q_i$ be the intersection of segments $CP_i$ and $AM$ for $1 \leq i \leq 29$. Compute $\frac{Q_8 Q_{20}}{Q_{12}Q_{24}}$.

I began by letting $P_i$ be $(2i,0)$, $A$ be $(0,0)$, and $B$ be $(60,0)$. Because the problem suggests that the ratio is constant, I let $\Delta ABC$ be equilateral, which means that $C$ has coordinates $(30, 30\sqrt 3)$. It follows that $M$ has coordinates $(45, 15\sqrt 3)$.

From here, we can see $AM$ has equation $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}$ and $CP_i$ has equation $$y=30\sqrt3 +\frac{900\sqrt 3}{2i-30}-\frac{30\sqrt 3 x}{2i-30}$$

Solving for the intersection, we see $Q_i$ has coordinates $\left(\frac{90i}{i+30}, \frac{90\sqrt 3 i}{i+30} \right)$, and it follows that the required ratio is $$\frac{\frac{216\sqrt 3}{19}}{\frac{200}{7\sqrt 3}}=\frac{567}{475}$$

However, while this approach gets the answer, it is both ugly and only works for one very specific case. So, I am looking for a nicer synthetic solution.

I have attached a diagram with $P_8$ and $P_{20}$. [image]

Comment: Your specific case is enough because affine transform preserves the length ratio.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is not a synthetic solution but a generalized version of your own idea. Moreover, in this way, the solution doesn't require much effort simply because we are not working with radicals compared to the equilateral-triangle case.

Let's assume $A=(0,0), B=(30,0), C=(2a,2b).$ Hence, we will have:
$$P_8=(8,0), \\ P_{20}=(20,0), \\P_{12}=(12,0), \\P_{24}=(24,0), \\ M=(a+15,b),\\
AM: y=\frac{b}{a+15}x,$$
and,

$$CP_{8}: y=\frac{b}{a-4}(x-8),\\CP_{20}: y=\frac{b}{a-10}(x-20),\\CP_{12}: y=\frac{b}{a-6}(x-12),\\CP_{24}: y=\frac{b}{a-12}(x-24).\\$$

Therefore, it is very easy to see that:

$$Q_{8}=(\frac{8(a+15)}{19},\frac{8b}{19}),\\Q_{20}=(\frac{4(a+15)}{5},\frac{4b}{5}),\\Q_{12}=(\frac{4(a+15)}{7},\frac{4b}{7}),\\Q_{24}=(\frac{8(a+15)}{9},\frac{8b}{9}).$$

Now that we have all the needed coordinates,

$$\frac{Q_8Q_{20}}{Q_{12}Q_{24}}=\frac{(\frac{4}{5}-\frac{8}{19})\sqrt{(a+15)^2+b^2}}{(\frac{8}{9}-\frac{4}{7})\sqrt{(a+15)^2+b^2}}=\frac{\frac{36}{5 \times 19}}{\frac{20}{9 \times 7}}=\frac{567}{475}.$$

One more thing to mention is that the solution suggests that there is nothing special about the indices of $Q$, and any other similar ratio is independent of $C$.